# What is the mechanism of Facebook to show post offline

Tags: android, android-imageview

I have a web server and I am getting data from it using JSON. For every time when I change the activity it makes call to server for getting data. I just want to save some data (Images and text) to available offline (Just like fb post) or the data once came from server shouldn't call again. So Far I used Universal Image Loader, Picasso and Volley for images. These libraries just save the data temporarily. When I relaunch the app the server again make call for data. I tried to save the images to local and the data to db as well. It's working fine but I want a better solution. Any help in this regard will be encouraged. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement your own content provider in order to provide complete offline support in your project.You can read more about it here [Content Providers](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html)